# Nvim autocomplition (lsp-zero+clangd) adds me includes

Tags: autocomplete, neovim

I'm having the trouble that in many occasions when I make an auto completion in a cpp file, it adds me the corresponding include library for it. In the project that I'm working right now it's a problem, how can I turn this functionality off? I only want the auto completion of the word, nothing extra.
I try to google it but with no luck. Some hint? Solution? keyword for this?

My set up is something like this:

```
local lsp = require("lsp-zero")

lsp.preset("recommended")

lsp.ensure_installed({
  'clangd',
  'pyright',
  --'python-lsp-server',
  'lua_ls',
  'texlab',
})

-- Fix Undefined global 'vim'
lsp.configure('lua_ls', {
    settings = {
        Lua = {
            diagnostics = {
                globals = { 'vim' }
            }
        }
    }
})


local cmp = require('cmp')
local cmp_select = {behavior = cmp.SelectBehavior.Select}
local cmp_mappings = lsp.defaults.cmp_mappings({
  ["<CR>"] = cmp.config.disable,
  ['<C-p>'] = cmp.mapping.select_prev_item(cmp_select),
  ['<C-n>'] = cmp.mapping.select_next_item(cmp_select),
  ['<C-y>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({ select = true }),
  ["<C-Space>"] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
})

-- disable completion with tab
-- this helps with copilot setup
cmp_mappings['<Tab>'] = nil
cmp_mappings['<S-Tab>'] = nil

lsp.setup_nvim_cmp({
  mapping = cmp_mappings
})

lsp.set_preferences({
    suggest_lsp_servers = false,
    sign_icons = {
        error = 'E',
        warn = 'W',
        hint = 'H',
        info = 'I'
    }
})

lsp.on_attach(function(client, bufnr)
  local opts = {buffer = bufnr, remap = false}

  if client.name == "eslint" then
      vim.cmd.LspStop('eslint')
      return
  end

  vim.keymap.set("n", "gd", vim.lsp.buf.definition, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "gD", vim.lsp.buf.declaration, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", 'gi', vim.lsp.buf.implementation, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "gr", vim.lsp.buf.references, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "K", vim.lsp.buf.hover, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>ws", vim.lsp.buf.workspace_symbol, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>e", vim.diagnostic.open_float, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "[d", vim.diagnostic.goto_next, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "]d", vim.diagnostic.goto_prev, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>ca", vim.lsp.buf.code_action, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>rn", vim.lsp.buf.rename, opts)
  vim.keymap.set("i", "<C-h>", vim.lsp.buf.signature_help, opts)
end)

lsp.setup()

vim.diagnostic.config({
    virtual_text = true,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the bottom of that file

```lua
local lspconfig = require('lspconfig')
lspconfig.clangd.setup {
    cmd = {"clangd", "--header-insertion=never"},
}
```

Then save and run `:so`

This has caused me a great deal of pain to figure out as well. After relaunching vim, try the auto completion again and watch how include statements do not get inserted anymore!!

The fact that `clangd` can't recognize a symbol that's been indirectly included by another file is incredibly frustrating in 2024

Comment: Peeeerfect! Header inerstion, has sense jeje. I'm still having problems... Do you use something like lsp-zero?

Comment: Yep, I use `lsp-zero` as well. Not sure what problems you're having but i probably wont be of much help. Im a neovim noob as well